# Nginx doesn't see default.conf under conf.d

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx 1.22 and Alpine Linux on my docker container. I copied my default.conf nginx file under /etc/nginx/conf.d. When I run nginx it doesn't look under conf.d but look http.d. Should I have the default.conf in http.d directory? People suggest locating config file in conf.d but my default Nginx settings:

```html
# Uncomment to include files with config snippets into the root context.
# NOTE: This will be enabled by default in Alpine 3.15.
#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

events {
        # The maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by
        # a worker process.
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

        # Includes virtual hosts configs.
        include /etc/nginx/http.d/*.conf;
}
```

And my default.conf file is:

```html
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;
    root /app/dist/defaultApp;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: You are including files from `/etc/nginx/http.d/*.conf`. What files are in the `http.d.` directory?

Comment: there was already a default.config file in http.d and I override that. I wonder if there were some changes about directory of conf files in last releases.